# How to make a new file on Windows in CMD?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I need a .cmd file that creates a new type of file when I click it. Is this possible? For example:
Click .cmd file
CMD pops up asking what file do I want to create...(eg: .css, .html) 
Then creates the file on the desktop. How would I do this? Or is this even possible on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Sort-of at least:

a. Ask only for file extension.

```
@echo off
set /p extension=What file extension?
copy NUL "%UserProfile%\Desktop\New %extension% file.%extension%"
```

b. Ask file Name and extension (from comments.)

```
@echo off    
set /p name=File name?
set /p extension=What file extension?
copy NUL %name%.%extension%
```

Comment: Almost, but it becomes New File .extension instead?

Comment: I fixed it, I took out the last 2 parts file.%extension%. Is there a way,  where it asks me to name the file, then the extension?

Comment: This is cool, nvm I got it!!! Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Kawohi: Well, I was intending it so you can say "css" and it creates a file "New css file.css" And yes, you can also ask for the name, you just need another `set /p name=File name? ` and then use `copy NUL %name%.%extension%` (or without the dot, if you prefer giving extensions with it).